# Split Table rows over two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've not posted here before so forgive me if this is incorrect or needs altering.

I'm currently trying to work on a way to split one table into two seperate tables after a certain row count.

So for example I have 2 columns of data with 2000 rows, I'd like to split that into two tables where the first table has the same 2 columns with the first 1000 results and the second table has the same two colums but with the last 1000 results. Hopefully that will make sense.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of sql server? Later version have features that make this easier. Also, this is probably a bad idea to begin with. You'll likely get better results simply by setting a good index on the existing table.

Comment: It's server 2005 and unfortunately it's a requirement due to certain limits, the data is stored and indexed on another table, this is purely for output and data services.

Comment: This sounds like a completely broken design (and requirement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ROWNUMER()
with FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6230e/3

```
-- First 1000
select * from 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1 asc) AS Row, 
    Col1, Col2 
FROM ur_table)d
where d.Row between 1 and 1000

-- Last 1000
select * from 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1 asc) AS Row, 
    Col1, Col2 
FROM ur_table)d
where d.Row between 1000 and 2000
```

Comment: This worked well with an insert for a new table. Changed the where to suit, good for multiple tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1000 column1, column2 order by column1 into new_table  from  tablex

SELECT * FROM (SELECT column1, column2 row_number() over (order by column1) as rownum 
from tablex) as a 
into new_table  from  tablex WHERE a.rownum between 1000 and 2001
```

This should limit the first one to 1000 records, and then the second one from 1001 - 2001

Comment: Does T-SQL have keyword LIMIT? I guess it's MYSQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I might use this approach. Please comment if you need explanation of any of the operations.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (Col1 INT)
CREATE TABLE #TableB (Col1 INT)

INSERT INTO #TableA (Col1)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5

DELETE #TableA
    OUTPUT DELETED.Col1 INTO #TableB
WHERE Col1 < 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good for creation if the data is of a finite number however the one I'm calling on isn't =(

Comment: Not sure I understand "if the data is of a finite number however the one I'm calling on isn't" - but you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter answer.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY Col1
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY


SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY Col1
OFFSET 1000 ROW FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```